# Object Memory Analysis in .NET

Tags: .net, memory

Is there a tool or a way to find out how much memory consumed by each DLL or object in .NET?
The more detail it analyzes the better. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&displaylang=en) which is free, or maybe the trial version of [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm).

Answer (score 3):

.NET Memory Profiler should allow you to do that: http://memprofiler.com/

Comment: upvoted because I've used .Net memory profiler and it provided lots of detail and was very helpful in tracking down memory usage problems.

Answer (score 2):

There are some decent memory profilers.. can look at this question

[What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Answer (score 1):

I always liked the [dot.Trace profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) from Jetbrains (as well as Resharper)